# Getting Dask map_blocks to make use of all available resources

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray, dask-distributed

I am using Dask to parallelize time series satellite imagery analysis on a cluster with a substantial amount of computational resources.

I have set up a distributed scheduler with many workers (`--nprocs = 56`) each managing one thread (`--nthreads = 1`) and 4GB of memory due to the embarrassingly parallel nature of the work.

My data comes in as an xarray that is chunked into a dask array and map_blocks is used to map a function across each chunk in order to generate an output array that will be saved to an image file.

```
data = inputArray.chunk(chunks={'y':1})                
client.persist(data)            
future = data.data.map_blocks(timeSeriesTrends.timeSeriesTrends, jd, drop_axis=[1])            
future = client.persist(future)                
dask.distributed.wait(future)
outputArray = future.compute()
```

My problem is that Dask does not make use of all the resources I have allocated to it. Instead it begins with very few parallelized tasks and slowly adds more as processes finish without ever reaching capacity.

This dramatically restricts the capabilities of the hardware I have access to as many of my resources spend most of their time sitting idle.

Is my approach appropriate for generating an output array from an input array? How can I best make use of the hardware I have access to in this situation?

Comment: Hi @daniel - this sounds like an interesting problem. I think it would be useful if you showed exactly how you were deploying dask and how you are opening and writing input and output files. From the xarray perspective, I would suggest looking at `xr.apply_ufunc` (assumes `timeSeriesTrends` takes/returns a numpy array) instead of `map_blocks`. Also, my feeling is that you are interacting with the dask api too much here, most of the parallelization should happen as a function of having a chunked dask array and you shouldn't need all the persist/wait/compute calls (just `load` at the end).

Comment: I recommend taking a look at the dask dashboard.  I suspect that it will convey more information about what is happening.  http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/diagnostics-distributed.html